# Excel: Pivot chart. How to exclude totals > 1?

Tags: excel, excel-2000

I'm using excel 2000.

I have a pivot table which looks like this

```
Color   Total
Blue    2
Green   1
Yellow  6
Black   7
```

How can setup the pivot chart so it excludes at values > 1?

I need to be able to do this without simply copying the data from the pivot table into a new location and removing the values not > 1

Is this possible in excel 2000?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the column and add a value filter.

Comment: which column? I see no value filter option

Comment: It should be the "Color" Column.  You'll see an option called "Filter."

Comment: I can't see that option on excel 2000

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement (I admit I don't now and never have had Excel 2000) a solution might be to add a column to your raw data (that tests whether the sum for that colour is greater than `1`) then add that column to the Page field and filter on it accordingly. With data for colours in ColumnA and values in ColumnB, ColumnC might have a formula such as:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,A2,B:B)>1
```

copied down to suit.